# Print the regex pattern where the string becomes invalid

Tags: c#, regex, automata

Given the regular expression

```
^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}$
```

For the language,

> All strings starting with double letters and ends with substring ab

I would like to know if it is possible to print the regex code where the string becomes invalid. This has got to do with regular expressions in Finite Automata.

For example i have these following input set of invalid strings,

```
abaa
aabb
aaba
```

I wanted to have an output like this,

```
abaa ^(aa|bb){1}
aabb ^(aa|bb){1}(a*)
aaba ^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}$
```

Comment: `aabb ^(aa|bb){1}(a*)` for this one, it's not really at this point of the pattern that the string becomes invalid, is it? That and your expression itself is not valid. It has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: sir @Jerry i have edited the unbalanced parentheses, and where is it not valid may i clarify?

Comment: @ryannjeffers [`(?!aa|bb)([ab]{2})a*[ab]{2}|(?:aa|bb)a*(?:(?!ab)([ab]{2}))`](https://regex101.com/r/OuWcbM/1/)

Comment: @ctwheels im sorry but may i know what's the point of this regex?

Comment: @ryannjeffers you said in your question `I would like to know if it is possible to print the regex code where the string becomes invalid`. That's what this regex does. It captures the errors in the string. For example, the first one `abaa`, it captures `ab` because it's incorrect. If you want a more *intense* regex, you can use [`\b(?:(?!aa|bb)(.{2})|aa|bb)(?:a*|(.*))(?:ab|(.{2}))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/OuWcbM/3), which catches correct and incorrect formatting and tells you which parts (if any) are incorrectly formatted (incorrect format if a capture group exists for that match).

Comment: @ctwheels oh sorry what it means is that it prints the regex based from the given regex code where the string becomes invalid. say we have input string `abaa`, it prints `^(aa|bb){1}` because the regex reading stops there since the string should start with either aa or bb only.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. That is different than what I assumed you wanted. What I would suggest is separating your regular expression into multiple parts and use string functions to split the string and test each part. So for `abaa`, you'd split and get `ab` and use the regex `^(aa|bb)` (note `{1}` is not necessary and is in fact redundant). Also, not that using `^(a{2}|b{2})` performs better. This gives you an indication as to which part of the string is malformed.

Comment: You said you want the code to print the regex when there is a failure. In case of `abaa`, the first part that tries to be matched is `^`, which is not a failure, so the next part is checked, `(aa|bb){1}`, and here there is a failure, so the regex printed is `^(aa|bb){1}`, right? In the case of `aabb`, the first part `^(aa|bb){1}` is successful, so the next part is checked, `(a*)` is also successful because `*` allows for 0 matches. Next, `(ab){1}` becomes a failure, so shouldn't `^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}` be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Regex from a string, if it is a malformed pattern it is going to throw an exception. You can create a loop that's going to get substring of the pattern an try to create a regex, if it fails just continue.

Once you have a Regex you can test for a match and store the last pattern that matched the input. So it would be something like this:

```
public static string FindBestValidRegex(string input, string pattern)
{
    var lastMatch = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var partialPattern = pattern.Substring(0, i + 1);
            var regex = new Regex(partialPattern);

            if (regex.IsMatch(input))
            {
                lastMatch = partialPattern;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return lastMatch;
}
```

Testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pattern = @"^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}$";

    Console.WriteLine(FindBestValidRegex("bbb", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestValidRegex("aabb", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestValidRegex("aaab", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestValidRegex("bbaab", pattern));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
^(aa|bb){1}(a*)
^(aa|bb){1}(a*)
^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}$
^(aa|bb){1}(a*)(ab){1}$
```